# Remap bash vi keys?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Dvorak and vi, so when I found out about the vi mode in Bash, I was very excited. However, it would be even better if I could remap the movement keys to be the ones that I use in vi (I swap keys around until the movement keys are back on the home row in Dvorak).

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the `bind` built-in command in `bash`, or if you want the changes to be uniform across all `readline` apps, modify `~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a file named '.inputrc' in your home directory.

```
# want vi to be the default editor for readline                      
set editing-mode vi                                            

# vi settings                                         
$if mode=vi                
    # normal mode                           
    set keymap vi-command                                 
    "j": beginning-of-history
    "l": backward-char
    "h": forward-char         
    "G": end-of-history
    # insert mode             
    set keymap vi-insert                          
    "jj": vi-movement-mode # remap escape   
$endif
```

These are my mappings, with the exception of `l` and `h`. I switched those here, to show you how you can switch keys.
I don't know the Dvorak keys you want, just modify all those keys like you want.

`man bash` describes all the possiblities.

Comment: what about `macOS` ?