# Custom key bindings for vi shell mode, ie, "set -o vi"?

Tags: bash, vi

I just discovered the wonders of `set -o vi`, and am curious if it is possible to customize this vi shell mode in some of the same ways you can customized vi or vim?

For example, create a custom key binding to map a more convenient key or key combo to `esc`?

If it's not currently supported, how difficult would it be to alter the source code of the program and hardcode in some customizations, or would that be a bad idea?

Comment: I found answer in here <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27699/remap-bash-vi-keys>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can change key mappings (for either vi- or emacs-like mode) with the `bind` builtin. This is actually a readline feature (so you can have vi-like bindings in all readline programs, not just bash).

The key you're looking for is called `vi-movement-mode`, and defaults to `\e` (escape). You could additionally bind it to (and this is rather silly) equals like this. The second line gets rid of the binding to escape:

```
$ bind "=":vi-movement-mode 
$ bind -r "\e"
```

Running `bind -p` will show you all the keys you can bind, and their current bindings (if any).

You can put `bind` commands in your `.bashrc`, or you can edit `~/.inputrc` to make it apply to all readline programs you run. The readline docs contain full details.

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks so much.  I was able to figure out how to bind key combos like `bind "Control-Space":vi-movement-mode` -- that works fine.  But for example in vim I have typing two characters in a row as trigger to `esc`, ie, if you type `jj` you'll return to normal mode.  This did not work when I tried it with bind, is there a special way to make it work?

Comment: @Jonah not that I know of off-hand, but I haven't perused the readline docs recently...

Comment: @chishaku you need to prefix Jonah's name with an at sign (`@`), or he won't get a notification.

Comment: @Jonah I just tried to do the same thing. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303282/in-bash-vi-mode-map-jk-to-exit-insert-mode You need quotes for some reason `bind '"jk":vi-movement-mode'`