# How do I remap function keys in readline bash vi (vi shell mode)?

Tags: bash, command-line, vi, readline

Regarding mapping function keys in vi readline, I have read these two stackexchanges:

- [Remap bash vi keys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27699/remap-bash-vi-keys)
- [Custom key bindings for vi shell mode, ie, "set -o vi"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74075/custom-key-bindings-for-vi-shell-mode-ie-set-o-vi)

---

I have a MacBookPro with a touchbar.  The function keys are always on, but unlike physical keys, the virtual touch bar function keys are tempermental and frequently inject junk into the commands i'm typing (this is particularly a problem when attempting to type an underscore...i get a lot of `F9`, `F10`, and maybe some `F11`).  I don't use these keys...so i wish i could disable them.  But, let's say that i could make them simply go to the end of the line.

This is one of my many attempts to map  to go to the end of the line (when in insert mode):

```
set editing-mode vi
$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-insert
    "<F9>": end-of-line
$endif
```

the result of typing "asdf" at a prompt is as follows:

> `TT->~$    []   (arg: 20)`

I have placed "[]", above, where the cursor remains after pressing `<F9>`, in case that is any help.

The variations i have tried are as follows:

- `"<F9>": end-of-line`
- `<F9>": end-of-line`
- `20: end-of-line`
- `"20": end-of-line`
- `"arg: 20": end-of-line`
- `(arg: 20): end-of-line`
- `"(arg: 20)": end-of-line`

---

**Update**: the following `.inputrc` is now working to "ignore" :

```
set keymap vi-insert
"\e[20~":redraw-current-line
```

Comment: I don't think that `"<F9>"` works in readline. To see what `F9` really turns into, run `cat` in your terminal and then press the `F9` key. You should see something like `^[[20~`. Once you have established the exact escape, bind it to `redraw-current-line`: `bind '"\e[20~": redraw-current-line'` (or whatever command you like). You should,  of course, use just the `"\e[20~": redraw-current-line` in `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @mosvy thank you.  i did try this line `"^[[20~": redraw-current-line` after cat showed me the `^[[20~` output.  Unfortunately i'm still getting `(arg: 20)`.  Could this be related to it being the MBP touch bar?  Does `bind '"^[[20~": redraw-current-line` go in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Try `"\e[20~"` or `"\033[20~"`, not `"^[[20~"`. `^[` is how escape (ASCII 27) is echoed back by the terminal when its `echoctl` flag is on.

Comment: Thanks - i did just try both of those.  I have to admit something, i went back and restested everything (same results), but the reason i retested is...i wasn't sourcing inputrc after each change.  So...this is important content...but i'm getting this when i source inputrc: `\e[20~:redraw-current-line: command not found`

Comment: `~/.inputrc` is not a shell script, you could not `source` it. To test if the binding works, either run `bind '"\e[20~": redraw-current-line'` in your current shell, or add just the binding the `~/.inputrc` and start a new shell. If you're using the emacs keybindings, you can also re-source the `~/.inputrc` file by pressing `Ctrl-x Ctrl-r`.

Comment: oh my stars, oh my stars, how wonderful to hit those F9-11 keys and *nothing happen*!  tell, me, why not post your comments as an answer so that i can accept them?  anyway, you are 100% right...(a) use `\e[20~` for <F9>, (b) use `redraw-current-line` as the command, and (c) start a new shell to source inputrc.  i have already put in 20-23 and find no reaction at all from purposeful (or accidental) input from <F9> <F10> and <F11>.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is insane but true...i was on a new server today and having forgotten completely about this question (and the answer buried in comments), I was actually googling for how to do this today.  I'm posting my answer for myself or for anyone else that is having problems disabling function key input in vi commandline:

1. create or edit your `~/.inputrc` file
2. to disable  through  (MacOS, Ubuntu, CentOS *at least*) use the following:

```
set keymap vi-insert
"\e[19~":redraw-current-line
"\e[20~":redraw-current-line
"\e[21~":redraw-current-line
"\e[22~":redraw-current-line
"\e[23~":redraw-current-line
```

As @mosvy indicates, redrawing the current line prevents the annoying "`(arg: 20)`" or "`(arg: 21)`" from ruining your command line input.